# Subsetting Dataframe based on datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I'm a bit confused on how to subset the date for specific months of my dataframe.

The dataframe is museum_data, which has visitor information.  The dataframe index is the datetime.

In the end, I want a lineplot of two lines, one of the number of visitors in each month for summer months and one of the number of visitors in each month for winter months, superimposed on themselves (I realize that this logically wouldn't be useful, but this is just for the sake of practicing subsetting dataframes for dates).

I came up with the below code but nothing is coming out:

```
museum_data["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(museum_data.index)

winter = {'Year':[2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019], 'Month':['Jan','Feb','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']}
summer = {'Year':[2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019], 'Month':['Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug']}

winter_months = []
for x in winter['Year']:
    for y in winter['Month']:
        new = str(x)+'-'+str(y)+'-01'
        pd.to_datetime(new)
        winter_months.append(new)

summer_months = []
for x in summer['Year']:
    for y in summer['Month']:
        new = str(x)+'-'+str(y)+'-01'
        pd.to_datetime(new)
        summer_months.append(new)

    
summer1 = pd.DataFrame(data=museum_data[museum_data['datetime'] in summer_months])

winter1 = pd.DataFrame(data=museum_data[museum_data['datetime'] in winter_months])


plt.figure(figsize=(16,6))
sns.lineplot(data=summer1, label='Summer')
sns.lineplot(data=winter1, label='Winter')
```

The line summer1 (and thus winter1) in the above code is giving me an error of:
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Please let me know how to get the code working and if there are any more efficient ways to subset the data accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [`Series.dt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html) method to access datetime properties like month. Then with `isin`, subset by month numbers. No loops or lists needed. And be sure to plot the numeric column like number of visitors not just the date time series.

```py
summer_df = museum_data[museum_data.index.dt.month.isin.([3,4,5,6,7,8])]
winter_df = museum_data[museum_data.index.dt.month.isin([1,2,9,10,11,12])]

plt.figure(figsize=(16,6))
sns.lineplot(summer_df['num_visitors'], label='Summer')
sns.lineplot(winter_df['num_visitors'], label='Winter')
```

Alternatively to subsetting, create a season column by conditional assignment in data frame to plot in seaborn [`lineplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html) with `hue` argument. To get date time as column to define x-axis series, `reset_index` is used.

```py
museum_data.loc[:, 'season'] = float('nan')
museum_data.loc[museum_data.index.dt.month.isin([1,2,9,10,11,12]), 'season'] = 'summer'
museum_data.loc[museum_data.index.dt.month.isin([3,4,5,6,7,8]), 'season'] = 'winter'

plt.figure(figsize=(16,6))
sns.lineplot('index', 'num_visits', hue='season', data=museum_data.reset_index())
```

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you.  This works perfectly for my application and should be marked as the answer.

Comment: Also wanted to mention for any future viewers of this answer - If your date column is not also the index of the df, then simply every occurrence of 'museum_data.index.dt' above to 'museum_data['NAME_OF_YOUR_DATE_COLUMN'].dt' where 'NAME_OF_YOUR_DATE_COLUMN' is the name of the date column in your df.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you need to change :

```
summer1 = pd.DataFrame(data=museum_data[museum_data['datetime'].isin(summer_months)])
```

and

```
new = pd.to_datetime(new) # otherwise this line will have no effect
```